# Merging two shapefiles in R

Tags: r, maps, shapefile, r-sp

I have a shapefile at a meso-level (`sul.ms`) which has a unique attribute called `MesoRegion`

```
library(brazilmaps)
sul.ms <- get_brmap(geo="MesoRegion",geo.filter = list(State = 43),class="SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
plot(sul.ms)
sul.ms@data$MesoRegion

 [1] 4301 4302 4303 4304 4305 4306 4307
```

[image]

I have another shapefile (download from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/my8lrvz6suf4ey7/AACuvzvemIXWFPyWeWlD1vPoa?dl=0))

which at municipality-level (from another source). This file also has a unique attribute called `ID`.

```
library(rgdal)
sul.mun <- readOGR("~","Rio_Grande_do_Sul_municipalities")
plot(sul.mun)
sul.mun@data$ID # should give 497 ID
```

[image: State map]

I can plot them on top of  each other which shows that each municipality is part of a meso region as shown below:

[image]

I want to create a table which has the municipality `ID` in one column and the corresponding `MesoRegion` in another column. Is there any way in R to do this presuming there is some way to clip the municipality using individual mesoregion and assigning the name of the mesoregion to the clipped district.

EDIT: I have tried to use the function `over`

```
library(sp)
over(sul.mun, sul.ms,returnList = T)
```

this does the work. However, I think there is an issue of a single municipality being a part of two mesoregions. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: okay. I have provide the shapefiles

Comment: Your first shapefile has no attribute `state.id`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question now to clear your doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution based on the use of "sf" functions:

```
library(sf)
#convert to "sf"
sul.ms_sf  <- sf::st_as_sf(sul.ms)
sul.mun_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(sul.mun)

# find centroids of the different municipalities
centroids  <- sf::st_centroid(sul.mun_sf)

# find out to which region they belong
inters <- sf::st_intersection(sul.ms_sf, centroids) %>% 
  sf::st_set_geometry(NULL)

# re-join with the municipalities to get the additional
# "nome" column
out <- dplyr::left_join(sul.mun_sf, inters) %>% 
  sf::st_sf(sf_column_name = "geometry")
head(out)  

Simple feature collection with 6 features and 7 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -56.66047 ymin: -31.95874 xmax: -51.95982 ymax: -27.53024
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs
    ID CD_GEOCODM  NM_MUNICIP                           nome MesoRegion State Region
1 4609    4300034     ACEGUÃ         SUDOESTE RIO-GRANDENSE       4306    43      4
2 4610    4300059 ÃGUA SANTA         NOROESTE RIO-GRANDENSE       4301    43      4
3 4611    4300109       AGUDO CENTRO OCIDENTAL RIO-GRANDENSE       4303    43      4
4 4612    4300208   AJURICABA         NOROESTE RIO-GRANDENSE       4301    43      4
5 4613    4300307     ALECRIM         NOROESTE RIO-GRANDENSE       4301    43      4
6 4614    4300406    ALEGRETE         SUDOESTE RIO-GRANDENSE       4306    43      4

plot(out["nome"])
```

[image: plot]

Seems to work, besides for one region on the East which stays as "NA".

Comment: The NA region is a lagoon, so everything is working as intended.